# Active menu item / category

Tags: menus, css

I was wondering if there's any way to discover which categories are "active" on a category archive page. This is for the purpose of menu highlighting.

To demonstrate, compare these:

(1) Parent category archive: http://building.mediumutm.ca/test-cat/ In the menu, the category is highlighted because it's active - cool. But so are both the dropdown menu links, its subcategories.

(2) Post in the parent category: http://building.mediumutm.ca/post-test-cat/ Working perfectly. Only the parent category is active and highlighted, not the dropdowns.

So it's really only (1) that's a problem, and I suspect it's not a CSS class issue because (2) works fine... So it that that archive page treats the subcategories as active? If so, can I disable that? Or what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, this *is* a CSS issue, caused by some difference in WP's classes applied. :)

First you are misinterpreting your "test" case 2:

1. Dropdown isn't highlighted because (despite what post body says) it's not actually assigned the subcategory.
2. The styling applied is from `.current-menu-parent`, since post is obviously not a term in taxonomy.

In your first case the class at work is `.current-menu-item`, since we *are* looking at the term in taxonomy. Next the CSS rules `.current-menu-item a` applies to *all* links inside of it and since dropdown HTML is inside top level item HTML it all gets styled as "current".

You should be limiting such rules to *immediately nested* links inside container — `.current-menu-item > a` (which is already done correctly for `.current-menu-parent > a`).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! And now I learn about child vs. descendant.